# git hook post-update doesn't do server-update-info

Tags: git

this is a topic that I couldn't solve so far so I hope some of you can help me.

This is my situation:

- There are two server: ServerA and ServerB
- On ServerA there are three standard repositorys (r1, r2, r3) and a central bare repository (b_rep). On r1,r2,r3 developers are working and are all clones of b_rep. So they are pushing and pulling from and into b_rep
- On ServerB there is one repository which also is a clone of the remote b_rep. This ServerB-rep is only pulling

My problem is: before each single pull in ServerB-rep I have to manually update-server-info in b_rep (on ServerA). I renamed hooks/post-update.sample into hooks/post-update and left its content unchanged.
As far as I understand this it is supposed to execute an update-server-info command on each push into b_rep. My aim is not having to manually update-server-info before each pull on ServerB-rep. But it doesn't work with the hook.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running the hook manually? Does it run?